# Understanding してっと

Tags: grammar

> 「そこで『動きづらい』とか言いますか、十代のガキが。……ま、俺達としちゃ、無様な指揮で俺達を殺さなきゃ言うこたないんですが。たとえそいつがくっそ無愛想なクソガキで、指揮官のくせに先陣きりたがる馬鹿で、下手に同調**してっと**気ィ狂いそうになる鉄面死神でも」
>
> 言うことだらけだなと、ほとんど聞き流しながら何の気なしに窓の外に目をやる。

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

The speaker is talking to his officer, who is a young boy. Does the bold part mean していると? Is it some kind of dialect?